# How can I get an email thread with the Microsoft Graph Node.js SDK?

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

i want to get an email thread using the microsoft graph mail api. i am using the microsoft graph SDK in javascript:

why is this not working:

```
  const messages3 = await client.api('/me/mailFolders/Inbox/messages').filter(`conversationId eq ${threadId}`).get();
```

i was expecting a list of emails that have that conversationId but all i got was this lousy error message:

Failed to reply to thread: Invalid filter clause

Answer (score 0):

The conversationid will be a string literal so you need either a single or double quote to denote that. Try something like

```
.filter(`conversationId eq '${threadId}'`)
```

Comment: thanks- also how can i get the message id from an incoming reply notification?

Comment: You should be able to do it with rich notifications https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks-with-resource-data